# How to grab value of promise and fire function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, async-await, promise

I know this is a common question asked, but I'm having a bit of an issue, trying to fire a function, ONLY when a promise has been returned.  I also want to grab the value returned of the promise.

- So I want to access an angular service, which seems to make an API call.
- Wait for the promise to resolve.
- Then store the promise returned as a value.
- And then fire the function `hello()`

It seems when I fire run my code below, `validPassengerId` and `hello()`console.logs, before the promise has resolved.

[image]

How do I rewrite this code, to:

- Wait for promise to resolve.
- Then grab the value of the promise resolved - validPassengerId.  (And then console.log it).
- And then fire the function `hello()`?

  ```
    function hello() {
        console.log("hello");
    };

    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let validPassengerId = _funnelBasketLuggageService.FindValidPassengerIdForBag(PassengerIds, bagsAssignedToPassengers, bag);
       resolve(validPassengerId);
    });

    promise.then(validPassengerId => {
        console.log("validPassengerId", validPassengerId);
        hello();
    });
  ```

Comment: I assume the function "_funnelBasketLuggageService.FindValidPassengerIdForBag(PassengerIds, bagsAssignedToPassengers, bag)", is async, can you validate that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `FindValidPassengerIdForBag` returns a promise, you do not need to wrap it in another promise. You would use it like this:

```
_funnelBasketLuggageService
  .FindValidPassengerIdForBag(PassengerIds, bagsAssignedToPassengers, bag)
  .then(validPassengerId => {
    console.log("validPassengerId", validPassengerId);
    hello();
  });
```

If `validPassengerId` is null with this code, then that must be what `FindValidPassengerIdForBag` is resolving its promise to. If you weren't expecting that, check the code of `FindValidPassengerIdForBag` or check that you're passing in valid parameters.

Comment: Thank you very much Nicholas!  You're right, `validPassengerId` was actually returning null and I didn't realise this was the correct value.  However, I think your code works well, because as you say, it's good to know, I do not need to wrap `FindValidPassengerIdForBag` in another promise.  I'll have a good read of this to understand this, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If in fact `_funnelBasketLuggageService.FindValidPassengerIdForBag` returns a promise, you solve this without creating your own `Promise`:

```
 function hello() {
      console.log("hello");
  };

  const promise = _funnelBasketLuggageService.FindValidPassengerIdForBag(PassengerIds, bagsAssignedToPassengers, bag);

  promise.then(validPassengerId => {
      console.log("validPassengerId", validPassengerId);
      hello();
  });
```

**Explanation** What you did was actually wrapping the `Promise` returned by `FindValidPassengerIdForBag` in another `Promise` that returns immediately.

If you absolutely have to wrap it in your own `Promise`, e.g. because you need to do some preprocessing, use `.then` instead of the return value of the function:

```
  function hello() {
      console.log("hello");
  };

  const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {_funnelBasketLuggageService.FindValidPassengerIdForBag(PassengerIds, bagsAssignedToPassengers, bag).then(id=>resolve(id));
  });

  promise.then(validPassengerId => {
      console.log("validPassengerId", validPassengerId);
      hello();
  });
```

Comment: Hi @Taxel- thank you very much for your solution.  I will have a play around with this and see if I can get it working..  `FindValidPassengerIdForBag` actually returns `null`, but does include a promise in this function as well.  Let me playaround with it and wrap my head around your explanation.  Thank you!